# When did the football match time fixed to 90 minutes?

Tags: football, history

As the international football matches are being played for several years. It may have different playing time/periods in the beginning.

I would like to know two things,

- Is there any play time for football matches other than 90 minutes? In
  cricket, there are 5 days matches, one day and 3 hours matches are
  there. (Just to point out, feel free to edit).
- When did the time fixed for 1.5 hours in international matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_association_football), it was in 1877 that the length of a game was set at 90 minutes.

Any professional game of football is set at 90 minutes but underage games don't use 90 minutes for their games. If the scores are level after 90 minutes in a knockout match then 30 minutes of extra time is used to find a winner.